# Why model is not updated?

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a custom function:

```
public changeClass() {
    this.studyPlan = this.studyPlanClone.slice();
    if (this.filter.classNumber) {
      this.studyPlan = this.studyPlan.filter(study => study.classNumber == this.filter.classNumber);
    }

    console.log(this.studyPlan);
  }
```

And HTML template is:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of studyPlan"></tr>
```

When I call `changeClass()` method it filters exists initial object and returns a new.

I can see correct result in console with 3 objects:

[image]

But on the page I have view with prev object `studyPlan`. It is not rendered.

Comment: `<tr *ngFor="let item of studyPlan">{{item.id}}</tr>`

Comment: Consider leaving some code or a [mcve] to show your issue and your whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a lot of code to go on, but the first thing I would check, is if you have Change Detection set to OnPush. This is the most common cause of "I updated variable in .ts, but it changed nothing in the browser"

Read about it here

https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/

Secondly, I don't know what Suresh meant, by manually triggering with a timeout and random function call. If you want to manually trigger change detection, please use the appropriate classes/functions.

Import in constructor

```
private _cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef
```

And when you want to detect changes, run

```
this._cdRef.detectChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

We may need to manually trigger change detection. Try to add the changeClass() block inside setTimeout().

```
setTimeout(()=>{
  this.changeClass();
}, 0);
```

Comment: Which is reason?